# Deleting User Profile Service Application

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, user-profile-service

Here's my issue, we have a 3-tier Farm where we deploy custom solutions (site templates, features, etc...).

We need to oversee what changes will be made to these custom solutions if we deploy the UPA on our application server.

However, someone deployed too early the UPA on the application server, so he was asked to delete it.

So we're not sure if redeploying the UPA now will be the same as if we had deployed it for the first time, so my question is:

Does deleting UPA revert back the SharePoint farm in the same state it was before deploying the UPA?

I'm sorry if I'm not clear enough about what my problem so doesn't hesitate to correct me or ask for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Delete and recreate the User Profile service, It will few impact which are not show stopper.

A user will lose their profile and data related to it. Target Audience(if you are using it) will not work, you have to recreate the group.

With new UPA, you have to run full sync to import all profiles from UPA.

[Removing User Profile Service Application](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/135888/removing-user-profile-service-application)

Answer (score 2):

Someone else can feel free to correct me, but I think it would be the same.  If for some reason something was left behind, your next deployment of UPA will overwrite it much like you've needed to do with some CU installs.